# Open Model on edit in list view

Tags: laravel-backpack

In backpack list view when I click in edit button then I get redirected to another page instead of I want model window where I edit and save the record. Also want for Add New.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The system really isn't designed for that behaviour to be changed, but if you REALLY need it i guess you can create new files in your resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud. This will make Backpack use those views instead of the ones in the package. You can copy views from the package and change them to fit your need:
- list.blade.php would include edit.blade.php in a bootrap modal;
- buttons/edit.blade.php should trigger the right modal on click;
- edit.blade.php should submit the form with ajax instead and catch the errors, to show them inside the modal;

The same process needs to be repeated for the create.blade.php file.

It won't be easy...